# histogram of bubble sort showing only lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, bubble-sort

[random lines coming in the histogram](https://i.stack.istrongtextmgur.com/ivZZw.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)


def animate(i):
    graph_data = open("bubble_sort.txt", 'r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split(" ")
    x_vals = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x = line.split(" ")
            x_vals.append(x)
            plt.xlabel("Numbers")
    plt.hist(x_vals)




ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Only lines are appearing no histogram. Check the image. Does my code has error or my file is not reading data properly
file data sample

7 11 13 19 42 49 61 78 79 123

Seperated by only spacebar

Comment: In `x_vals.append(x)`, `x` is a list of one string. Replacing with `x_vals.append(float(x[0]))` could be helpful. Also, the test `if len(line) > 1` makes that numbers of length 1 (so, the numbers from 0 to 9) are skipped. Please, first try to make a plot without animation, and only when the result is the desired one, add animation code back in,

Comment: thanks for the help @JohanC it works properly now.